# How can Aoshi Shinimori walk/run/fight when he got shot in both legs?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

In the fight with Kanryu Takeda, Aoshi Shinimori gets shot in both legs, in what appears to be above the kneecaps. Yet come a few months later, he is able to fight perfectly fine in the Kyoto arc, despite these injuries. 
Does Nobuhiro Watsuki ever explain this at all? Or is it different in the manga in some way, where he doesn't get as grevious of injuries? I'm looking for either an official explanation by the author or by the source.

**TLDR: How can Aoshi Shinimori walk/fight with gunshot wound injuries?**

Comment: recovery from injuries are nearly always glossed over in that genre. Going from would be crippled IRL to stronger than before and ready for a rematch in a few months is actually longer than average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While bullet wounds *can* be very dangerous, [according to this Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2015/12/what-really-happens-when-you-get-shot/) by a combat medic, they can also be relatively trivial. The author retells the story of a man shot in the chest and neck six times who remained fully alert and responsive, and survived. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunshot_wound), *"depending on the extent of injury, management can range from superficial wound care to limb amputation."* A bullet to the leg could shatter your femur, or it could cause so little damage a doctor would just slap a bandage on it (assuming the bullet passed through).

Moreover, a man like Aoshi would likely have trained in martial arts pain management techniques. Aoshi may well feel pain from his injuries during the Kyoto arc but could ignore it.

Comment: I can buy this. No luck with anything from the manga or from the author though? Oh well.

Comment: Not that I know of, though my knowledge is limited. OTOH, I don't think he needed to explain it. As @ratchet freak wrote in a comment on your post, fast recovery from near-fatal wounds is a common shonen trope, and I'm sure Watsuki's audience accepted this without a blink.

Answer (score 1):

The damage done by a bullet is prevalent if it hits major tissue or functioning essential organs. People shot multiple times continue to move about. Painfully YES but if Nothing is majorly damaged you can continue moving about.